# Page layout for community page in SP213 online (365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, page-layout, css

Our content editors have created a new community subsite and whilst it has adapted to the master page i have created it seems to have its own page layout...but i can't find this anywhere or work out which ones it using.

Whatever its using its come in with a lot of extra CSS DIV's and tables etc and i want to try and remove this? Anyone ran into this issue or know how to modify the community template?

or do i just need to modify the aspx pages?

Cheers,

S

Answer (score 2):

According to the ONET for Community sites it uses a page layout called welcomelayout2.aspx

Located at `~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/welcomelayout2.aspx`

Full Module for default page:

```
<Module Name="TopicsDefaultPage" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
            <File Url="Default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
                <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/welcomelayout2.aspx, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/welcomelayout2.aspx" />
                <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
            </File>
        </Module>
```

Comment: thanks! been trying to track that down for a while...will have a look at that.

Comment: hmm dont think thats the case for office 365 environments...

Comment: Strange, you'd figure that they should not write the same thing twice:/

Comment: Agreed...it looks to me when you create a community site the pages are created as .aspx pages without any reference to page layouts which is frustrating as i now need to make the same changes to 7 pages which are all involved in the community site!